# Python Flask for loop doesn't print all words on website

Tags: python, flask

I am a python beginner and I want to print this list in on my website.
I tried this code in **Python Flask**:

```
@app.route('/send')
def send():
    greetings = [ 'Hello', 'how', 'are ', 'you']

    for words in greetings:
        return render_template('test.html', greetings= words)
```

i also wrote this in my html file:

```
<h1>{{greetings}}</h1>
```

But why it always only print 'Hello' instead of all word in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do your loop in template, not on your route controller.

```py
@app.route('/send')
def send():
    greetings = [ 'Hello', 'how', 'are ', 'you']
    return render_template('test.html', greetings=words)
```

```py
{% for word in greetings %}
    <h1>{{word}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you only have "Hello" in your output is because you have a `return` inside your `for` loop so in this case, after the first iteration of the loop the template will be rendered.

In order to render all the words, pass the `greetings` list to your template:

```
@app.route('/send')
def send():
    greetings = [ 'Hello', 'how', 'are ', 'you']
    return render_template('test.html', greetings=greetings)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see the list as a list in your website, then do

```py
@app.route("/send")
def send():
    greetings = ['Hello', 'how', 'are ', 'you']
    return render_template('test.html', greetings=greetings) # ['Hello', 'how', 'are ', 'you']
```

If you want it to be a sentence then it would be

```py
@app.route("/send")
def send():
    greetings = ['Hello', 'how', 'are ', 'you']
    return render_template('test.html', greetings=" ".join(greetings)) # Hello how are you
```